# Framing question for a chicken run

Tags: framing

Hi I am building a 2x4 framed chicken run that will be 20x14 ft. Being that this is just a chicken run, is there really a need for using double plates on top of the frames? The roof will be light weight corrugated panels so I don't think there will be a need for a double plate but wanted to check with the experts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is usually the studs that do most of the weight holding.  Double plates do stiffen the walls when two or more top pieces must be joined and provide anchor points at corners to attach to the other wall, plus some weight holding.  Do you get any snow loading?

Answer (score 2):

In most jurisdictions, (LAHJs) how you build a chicken run, dog house, or pony shed is left pretty much up to you.

Mind you, I interpret "chicken run" as open or just fence on top, where "chicken coop" or "chicken shed" brings a roof to mind. If you have a roof in mind, and you're framing from 2x4s, you're going to need to build a truss to span 14 feet. Again, for this purpose, most LAHJs have no problem with you home-building it, and you can find advice from cooperative extension sites on building farm buildings that will show you how to do that with 2x4's and plywood gussets - you don't have to buy engineered manufactured trusses unless you want to, or your LAHJ is weird about animal shelters.

If you get snow load, even just chicken wire will catch snow and get loaded. So you'd still need trusses for 2x4 framing.

However, **even** in "real structures for people" double top plates are not particularly needed, as the "[Advanced framing](https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/article/the-pros-and-cons-of-advanced-framing)" also known as "[Optimum Value Engineering](https://www.apawood.org/advanced-framing)" framing method shows. That does require simple things like putting rafter or truss loads right on top of vertical studs, not "just randomly anywhere" and depending on the top plate to send the load to the studs.